# Sci-Fi anime of little boy with floating friend/companion

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember seeing a key visual/announcement of a sci-fi anime on reddit about 1-2 years ago. It was a detailed art style with blue and I think purple colors. I don't remember what the anime was about, just that it had a boy(mc) and a cute floating round/oval companion that I think was white. Both were on the key visual, standing somewhere outside, I think they were standing in either a town or in a landscape.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What made this science fiction?

Comment: @DavidW I'm not sure about the exact plot. I remember reddit calling it sci Fi, I think it might have been about space

Answer (score 2):

Could this be *[Ayaka: A Story of Bonds and Wounds](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/preview-guide/2023/summer/ayaka-a-story-of-bonds-and-wounds/.199177)* (2023)? A young boy gains elemental powers. There's a very heavy blue/purple vibe going on in the first few episodes. He makes a sort of floating ball of water as a companion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not an anime, but could this be the video game *[Genshin Impact](https://genshin.hoyoverse.com/en/)*?

[image]

There are a bunch of these in different colours